# Function taking in Objects when it should accept string variables

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv

The Logger picked up a error where the string variable in a function argument (Function being get_whole_number) is considered an object and we don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
# Import the required libraries
import os
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
import glob
import logging
import csv

# Constants defined for sheet names and a regular expression pattern for CSI numbers
SHEET_NAME = 'BasisOfEstimate'
COSTSHEET_NAME = 'CostSummary'
DATASHEET_NAME = 'HardCostDetailLevel2'
CSI_NUMBER_PATTERN = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]+')

#.......................................... Functions ............................................#

# This function takes a string and returns the first group of non-alphabetic characters.

def get_whole_number(str):
    if str is None or str == "":
        return ""
    match = WHOLE_NUMBER_PATTERN.match(str)
    return match.group().strip()

 

def _float(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except Exception:
        return 0.0

def generate_csv_row(FMS_ID, project_name, row_data):
    FMS_ID = FMS_ID
    vendorTotal = row_data[('Vendor: AI \nEngineers \nTotals:','Unnamed: 10_level_1')]
    csv_row = (FMS_ID, project_name, vendorTotal, row_data)
    print(FMS_ID)
    return csv_row

def process_excel_file_as_pd(data, FMS_ID, project_name):
    output_rows = []
    current_Fms_Id = None 
    current_Vendor_Total = None
    i = 1
    while i < len(data):
        row = data.iloc[i]
        FMS = row[('FMS ID \n Capital Projects', 'Unnamed: 1_level_1')]
        Ven_div = [('Vendor: AI','Unnamed: 10_level_1 ')]

        if FMS.startswith('FMS ID'):
                current_Fms_Id = FMS
                i = i + 1
                continue #rows with FMS info don't contain data 
        if Ven_div != '':
            current_Vendor_Total = Ven_div
            #Vendor totals contain data
        if FMS == 'copy above cell and insert copied cell above the row':
            if current_Fms_Id is not None and current_Fms_Id.startswith('PVO28-ISS'):
                break
            current_Fms_Id = None 
            current_Vendor_Total = None
            i = i + 2
        csv_row = generate_csv_row(FMS_ID, project_name, current_Fms_Id, current_Vendor_Total, row)
        output_rows.append(csv_row)
        i = i + 1
        return output_rows
```

We were expecting the data from a excel spreadsheet to a csv file with the data transferred. But it didn't do it and now were stuck.

Comment: This code never actually calls the `get_whole_number()` function ...

Comment: In fact, this code has no main-level function, so _nothing_ is ever called.  This cannot be the full code.

Comment: Show us the full code, and the error.